# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List for Hierarchy Ref Cursor function result

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations, ref-cursor

I'm trying to call a procedure function in DB and to mapped the Hierarchy answer to entity class using hibernate.The entities that I wrote suppose to represent the result structure that is returned from a ref cursor function.
The result of the function has a property which is a list of objects and inside that object there is also a property that is also a list of another objects.
On application startup I get the MappingException as I wrote in the title above.
I tried to add the annotation @OneToMany but it is not working because it is not looking at tables in DB.
Again, the entities represent the function result and not select from table tables.
Someone has any idea of any annotation that could prevent from this exeception to araise in the application startup?

**My Entities:**

**Main Entity that call to procedure function (rc):**

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "GetDeliveryOptionsRC.runFunction",
        query = "{ ? = call fn_get_delivery_options_rc_dev(:i_account_number,:i_work_order_number,:i_task_id,:i_task_type,:i_content_type_code,:i_sap_operator_code)}", resultClass = GetDeliveryOptionsRC.class,
        hints = {@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true")})
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetDeliveryOptionsRC")
public class GetDeliveryOptionsRC implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long rownum;

    @Column(name = "ACCOUNT_NUMBER")private Long accountNumber;
    @Column(name = "TASK_TYPE")private Long taskType;
    @Column(name = "CONTENT_TYPE")private String contentType;
    @Column(name = "CONTENT_TYPE_CODE")private Long contentTypeCode;
    @Column(name = "MESSAGE_CODE")private Long messageCode;
    @Column(name = "MESSAGE_ERROR_CODE")private Long messageErrorCode;
    @Column(name = "MESSAGE_ERROR_DESCR")private String messageErrorDescr;
    @Column(name = "DELIVERY_OPTIONS")private List<DeliveryOptionsRC> deliveryOptions;

//getters & setters

}
```

**Delivery Options Entity:**

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "DeliveryOptions")
public class DeliveryOptionsRC implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DELIVERY_TYPE") private String deliveryType;
    @Column(name = "DELIVERY_DESCR") private String deliveryDescr;
    @Column(name = "PRICE") private Double price;
    @Column(name = "EXISTS_FLAG") private String existFlag;
    @Column(name = "IS_VALID") private String isValid;
    @Column(name = "IS_SAP_ORDER") private String isSapOrder;
    @Column(name = "IS_OTHER_ADDRESS") private String isOtherAddress;
    @Column(name = "IS_SCHEDULE_NEEDED") private String isScheduledNeeded;
    @Column(name = "PICKUP_SOURCE") private String pickupSource;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=ChargeJobs.class, mappedBy="deliveryOptionsRC", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Column(name = "CHARGE_JOBES") private List<ChargeJobs> chargeJobs;


//getters & setters

}
```

**Charge Jobs Entity:**

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "ChargeJobs")
public class ChargeJobs implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "JOB_OFFER_ID") private Long jobOfferId;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "JOB_CODE") private String jobCode;
    @Column(name = "PRICE") private Double price;
    @Column(name = "QUANTITY") private Long quantity;

//getters & setters

}
```

**The RC function:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION YES_SIMPLE.fn_get_delivery_options_rc_dev (i_account_number NUMBER,
                                                                                                  i_work_order_number NUMBER ,
                                                                                                  i_task_id NUMBER ,
                                                                                                  i_task_type NUMBER,
                                                                                                  i_content_type_code NUMBER,
                                                                                                  i_sap_operator_code NUMBER
                                                                                                   )
RETURN sys_refcursor
is

out_ref sys_refcursor ;
ret  tr.delivery_options_list_t;
xml sys.xmltype;

begin



     ret:= TR.fn_get_delivery_options    (p_account_number => i_account_number,
                                                   p_work_order_number =>i_work_order_number,
                                                   p_task_id =>i_task_id,
                                                   p_task_type =>i_task_type,
                                                   p_content_type_code =>i_content_type_code,
                                                   p_sap_operator_code => i_sap_operator_code) ;

    open out_ref for
    select ret.Account_number Account_number

                  ,ret.Task_Type Task_Type,
                  ret.content_type content_type,
                  ret.content_type_code content_type_code,
                  ret.message_code message_code,
                  ret.message_error_code message_error_code,
                  ret.message_error_descr message_error_descr

    ,cursor(select DELIVERY_TYPE ,
                  DELIVERY_DESCR ,
                  PRICE  ,
                  EXISTS_FLAG    ,
                  IS_VALID    ,
                  IS_SAP_ORDER    ,
                  IS_OTHER_ADRESS   ,
                  IS_SCHEDULE_NEEDED  ,
                  PICKUP_SOURCE,
                  cursor(select *  from(select * from(select * from table(select ret.delivery_options from dual) ))) charge_jobs 
    from table(select ret.delivery_options from dual) ) delivery_options
    from dual;
   return out_ref;

end;
```

**Getting the following result:**

```
ROWNUM  1
ACCOUNT_NUMBER  13
TASK_TYPE   1
CONTENT_TYPE    OTT
CONTENT_TYPE_CODE   2
MESSAGE_CODE    98
MESSAGE_ERROR_CODE  98
MESSAGE_ERROR_DESCR 
DELIVERY_OPTIONS    <Cursor>


                DELIVERY_TYPE   T
                DELIVERY_DESCR  Tech
                PRICE   0
                EXISTS_FLAG N
                IS_VALID    Y
                IS_SAP_ORDER    N
                IS_OTHER_ADRESS N
                IS_SCHEDULE_NEEDED  Y
                PICKUP_SOURCE   
                CHARGE_JOBS <Cursor>
                                    JOB_OFFER_ID    900310
                                    JOB_CODE    D80
                                    PRICE   0
                                    QUANTITY    1
```

Comment: I would say that this is not possible because HIbernate can not use the cursor you are returning from the procedure.

Comment: Hi,we use this method of ref cursor successfully in cases where the result is flat and not hierarchy. The ref cursor use select with fields names from the result and the Hibernate mapping this to the entity in Java